# $\text{Hom}_S (\ell, \text{Hom}_S (T, M\otimes_R N)) \cong \text{Hom}_S (\ell, M\otimes_R N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

This concerns the proof of Lemma 1.2.17 in Bruns' & Herzog's *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*. Let $\varphi: (R, \mathfrak{m}, k) \rightarrow (S, \mathfrak{n}, \ell)$ be a ring homomorphism of local Noetherian rings. Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, and $N$ is a finitely generated $S$-module which is flat over $R$. Set $T = S/\mathfrak{m}S$. The first claim in the proof is that there is a natural isomorphism

$$\text{Hom}_S (\ell, \text{Hom}_S (T, M\otimes_R N)) \cong \text{Hom}_S (\ell, M\otimes_R N)$$

since both modules can be identified with the submodule $U= \{z\in M\otimes_R N : \mathfrak{n}z = 0\}\subset M\otimes_R N$. I have no problem believing that $\text{Hom}_S(\ell, M\otimes_R N) \cong U$ since in general $\text{Hom}_R (R/I, M) \cong \{ x\in M : Ix = 0\}$ when $R$ is a ring, $I\subset R$ is an ideal, and $M$ is an $R$-module. I am lost as to why the LHS of the equation can also be identified by $U$. Am I missing something crucial? Is $\text{Hom}_S(T, M\otimes_R N) \cong M\otimes_R N$?

Comment: Maybe I answered my own question... Using the tensor-hom adjunction, we have that

$$\text{Hom}_S (\ell, \text{Hom}_S(T,M\otimes_R N)) \cong \text{Hom}_S(\ell\otimes_S T, M\otimes_R N)$$

But then $\ell\otimes_S T \cong T/\mathfrak{n}T \cong \ell$ since $\mathfrak{n}T \supset \mathfrak{m} T$.

Comment: Yes, you did. (I was about to post this as a hint.)

Comment: Thanks! It's nice to have confirmation